# Reason behind extra 8dp margin in a view ? not ways to solve

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In my activity xml file i am get an extra 8dp margin in Left side in  view(Represented as Underline).

- Reason for getting 8dp margin extra in "view"? (underline under TextView.)
- i have given 48dp left margin in that view.

above that view i have

```
<TextView> which has a drawable icon in left.
```

- with left margin 24dp and drawable padding 24dp.

Reason for doing.

- I am try to create an underline under my words using a view with black background.
- i have given 48dp as left margin in xml.but as shown in photo i am getting 56dp.
- difference between lines is 8dp.

[image: screenshot of my app]

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#FAFAFA"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hysterics.delhishop.AccountSetting">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/hello_user"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_account_information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_18dp"
            android:drawablePadding="24dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/account_information"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_home_black_18dp"
            android:drawablePadding="24dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/account_address"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
................
................

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

here is my activity file.

```
public class AccountSetting extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG_USER_NAME_DIALOG = "edit_text_dialog";

@InjectView(R.id.account_setting_toolbar) Toolbar accountSettingToolbar;
@InjectView(R.id.user_account_information) TextView userAccountInformation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_setting);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    setToolbar();
}
```

- thank you in adavnce :-)

Comment: problem is not clear from image..

Comment: difference between lines is 8dp.

Comment: @abhishek, please edit the image and mark the place, where you are facing the issue. Are you facing the problem with <View>? If So, you say, the images have 24dp padding on left and the textview has a 24dp padding on its left. That makes it 48dp and you want the line to start where the text starts? And did you test it on real device and made sure you get the same there as well?

Comment: @VamsiChalla sir, This snapshot is from genymotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set the underline view's layout_width="match_parent" and layout_gravity="center".
After views measure:
- the linear parent view's width is 1080px;
- the underline view's width is 936px ( because of layout_marginLeft="48dp"(144px))
When views layout:
- Because the linear parent's orientation is "vertical", so when set layout_gravity="center" equal with layout_gravity="center_horizontal".
- For a "center_horizontal" child, **the linear parent will margin the child view's X-center with it's X-center**
So the X-axis of underline view will be (in px): 
`540 (X-center of parent) + 144 (48dp margin left) - 468 (half of child's width) = 216px (72dp)`
That why with layout_gravity="center", you will see the underline view will get 24dp extra margin.

Answer (score 0):

It because your views width is **match_parent** & `android:layout_marginLeft` & `android:layout_gravity="center"`
is causing view to shift outside of screen bound.

[See this for more information..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212318/1677824)

Try with removing center layout_gravity from your Views(which draws line)

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and use

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_large"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_xxlarge"
```

Comment: reason for that..? i have given background color black.. i not looking for other ways i am just looking for the reason

Comment: there se no inner spacing

Comment: space_large is 24dp, space_xxlarge is 48 dp, your textviews are using space_large

Comment: reason for that? i have no idea why am i getting 8dp extra margin..?

Comment: hehe.. i have spend alot time. i know other ways. but dont know why? :-/

Comment: can you mark this ques a useful so that intalligent once can see this ques?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding drawable padding to the icon and the marginLeft is completely different between the underline and the icon. And also you have to take into account the size of the icon itself. I would be surprised that it would have the exact same align.

Instead of this, why don't you use an horizontal LinearLayout with weight between two linear layouts, one with the icon and another transparent view with the same height as the underline, and the other linear layout that contains text and underline perfectly aligned. No margins no nothing, just distribution of weight. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Account Information"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is just one possible solution that can guarantee you exact alignments.

Comment: Dear andriodpotato7, i have already sorted that with other way.. i am just looking for the reason.. not other solutions

Comment: what other way did you sort it out?

Comment: It can be so many things. It can be the font size, because the font is bold so it pushes the drawable or something, it can be because of the drawable. As I said, it is not a good solution to play around with margins this way

Comment: obviously. office senir guys wont wait for me till i sort it out.

Comment: I'm asking you what was your solution. Maybe in your solution lies the answer for your question.

Comment: its just a temporary solution. by giving a 8dp extra in drawble padding.or by deleting 8dp margin from underline view

Answer (score 0):

According these two lines:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_18dp"
android:drawablePadding="@dimen/space_large"
```

You'll have a drawable of width `18dp`, then a padding of `@dimen/space_large`, which looks to be `24dp` for a total of `42dp` of padding between the left edge of the `TextView` and the start of the text itself.

However, the `layout_marginLeft` on your lines is `@dimen/space_xxlarge` or `48dp`. As one is `42dp` and the other is `48dp`, they won't align. You'll need to change one or the other if you want the elements to appear visually in line.

Comment: That is not the answer for my ques .. It's not 48dp.. M getting 48 + 8 = 56dp.. When m putting left margin of 48 dp.. In view

Comment: ianhanniballake sir, can you help me out in one of my ques.. or help me edit it.. plz ;_) .. thank you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240221/can-i-put-clickable-icon-right-to-title-in-collapsing-tool-bar-not-in-tool-bar

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

There are multiple view in your layout and you are using layout_gravity="center". So `View` is trying to adjust itself to center inside `LinearLayout`. Just try removing `layout_gravity` or use `layout_gravity="left"`.

[image: Missing icon width]

You have added marginLeft of 24dp also drawablePadding of 24dp and you say a total of 48dp But you forget the width of drawable icon. So, the first latter of ACCOUNT "A" is not at 48dp margin.

You are using `LinearLayout` and everyting is at the left side so there is no need of any gravity.

Also you say removing gravity from `View` makes it 36dp from left. YES, thats correct. You missed Drawable Icon width from your calculation.

Set `layout_margin` of `View` equals `48dp + width of icon`. Thats the reason you got I think.

Comment: am usiing layout gravity center.. does not mean it will be at center.  bez am using linear layout

Comment: well with out giving layout gravity. it start's at 36dp but i have given 48dp margin. again another ques arise why is it starting after 36dp.

Comment: Do other things like TextView and Headers are at correct position ? You mean only your Divider `View` is not at correct position... Right ?

Comment: i have completed that page. by justing giving drawable padding 8dp extra  in text view. am just looking for reason

Comment: dude am asking about underline not text view. both are different views.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```html
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

from your view it will fix your problem.

Comment: dude.. read my ques title. not ways to solve.. all i need is a reason for why?