# layout_gravity center along with layout_marginRight issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am not able to get reason why there is difference in below two views, only difference is layout_gravity **center** is missing in second one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        />
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing **android:layout_gravity="top|center"** I think that **margin_right** is making go the view to the left

[image]

Could that be it?

**Edited**

I used your code to see and this is the result
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

here is my ques.

[Reason behind extra 8dp margin in a view ? not ways to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211152/reason-behind-extra-8dp-margin-in-a-view-declared-in-activity-xml)

under my words there is an underline..

- i represented it as a view with black background.
- with leftmargin of 48dp.
- but as you see there is an 8dp extra.
- i am looking for a genuine reason.
- not other ways to sort it out.
- check my link for further details.